# Is Responsive Web Design necessary?

Tags: android, iphone, css

I am just wondering about Responsive Web Design and its necessity. Since new smartphones have resolutions similar to 1024x768 and the vast majority of web sites work well under this resolution, for what reason may we care about how mobile phones will show our design? Is the whole conversation about smaller resolutions or am I thinking the wrong way?
Thank you

Comment: Resolution is not the issue with responsive Web design. Screen density is.

Answer (score 3):

It's not about resolution, it's about readability and usability on a small screen.

Comment: I am trying to understand...Suppose the following css:            @media only screen  and (max-width: 680px) {...}                                                             How it's not about resolution since the above rules will be applied only to resolutions less than 680px? A mobile phone with 900px screen width will not be affected; however the readability in the last one may be problematic since its screen may be 4 inches only.

Comment: @ILIAS: You should test not only for the pixel size, but also the resolution (meaning the DPI) - see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/ for some examples.  (Disclaimer: I'm only going by what I read - I haven't used this stuff for real.)

Answer (score 0):

According to Andy Rubin there are about 600 different Android devices available in the market right now. Supporting all of them is impossible, right? At least that is what we see in tech blogs throughout the Internet. Funnily enough, fragmentation seems to be much bigger problem to people who don't work in Android development or have good understanding of the platform than to people who do.
That meaning, you could have more than 100 different resolutions for your app, maybe some are big like 7 inch, 4 inch, etc.
The responsive design, could be very good for the developer and designer, and if you need implement the portrait and landscape view.

Responsive design not is mandatory, but could be more easy for you in the moment to publish your app in tablets, phone devies, etc.

Android design cannot be approached the same way one would design for iOS. Android device categories are a continuum not tablet / phone steps. If we understand how to approach the problem of design from the beginning we endup building apps that suit most of the devices much better.

Don't build two separate versions! Build one scalable one!

You can [read more here](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/11/design-patterns-for-responsive-android.html)